# Importing Vuex Plugins without defining a Store

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuex

so one of my store modules looks like this

```
export const state = () => ({
  posts: []
})

export const getters = {}

export const actions = {}

export const mutations = {
  fetchedPosts(state, posts) {
    state.posts = posts
    console.log("fetched")
  },

  pushPost(state, post) {
    state.posts.push(post)
    console.log("pushed")
  }
}
```

I want to use the `vuex-persistedstate` plugin but following their docs and the Vuex Plugin Docs https://vuex.vuejs.org/guide/plugins.html i didnt find a way to use the plugin inside my store, thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You just need to mention it once in your `store/index.js`:

```
import Vue from 'vue'
import Vuex from 'vuex'
Vue.use(Vuex)
import createPersistedState from 'vuex-persistedstate'
import posts from '~/store/posts.store'

....

export default new Vuex.Store({
  state:     { ... },
  mutations: { ... },
  actions: { ... }, 
  modules: { 
    posts,
    ... 
  },
  plugins: [createPersistedState()]
})
```

in your posts module:

```
const state = () => ({ ... })
const getters = { ... }
const mutations = { ... }
const actions = { ... }
export default { namespaced: true, state, getters, actions, mutations }
```

that works for me.

Comment: But im using Nuxt so i dont have one exporting router, not even in my index.js router file, so im not sure where to put it... when im home i can post you my index.js router file but its basicly a serverInit function and thats it without any state etc... and in Nuxt i also dont have to import the Modules into the main Route file

Comment: @Badgy you don't mention it anywhere, even in tags. Please update your question.

Comment: there is no code to add it in since this is basicly my store, i also readed the docs and found your way of solving it but the problem why im asking here is that im not sure how to implement it, still thanks for your answer its a  very good summarize

Comment: Ok i found it in the Nuxt docs, to be fair it was stupid from myself to only check the vuex docs and not the nuxt docs, still thank you for your answer im sure it will help a lot of people